# how to find below text by xpath

Tags: html, xpath

```
<td class="subject" id="td_880700">
<a href="thread-htm-fid-75-type-148.html" class="f14 view">[health]</a>
<a href="read-htm-tid-880700.html" name="readlink" 
id="a_ajax_880700" class="subject_t f14"><b><font color=#FF0000>man's best love</font></b></a>&nbsp;
```

I wanna record text "man's best love"in above code,but there are many text as "man's best love"in different table i need to record as a array in ios ,how to generate a xpath to find all location such as "man's best love"title in all html script?

I create a xpath to identify text as: `//td[@class='subject'/a/a/b`, but it didn't work, please

Comment: if just find "man'best love" in below link, what it would be in Xpath?        <a href="read-htm-tid-900733.html" name="readlink" id="a_ajax_900733" class="subject_t f14">man's best love</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
//td[@class='subject']/a/b/font/text()
```

If you're using Chrome, you can right click on the element in Inspector and click **Copy XPath**.

Answer (score 1):

`//td[@class='subject']/a/b/font/text()`

I've tried at http://www.xpathtester.com/test but need to close the `td` and add quotes around the color attribute